# CYGWIN: all paths are in cygwin/ format and not understandable by java

Tags: java, cygwin, classpath

I have setup cygwin and want to use it to run java applications.

When I run 
**java -cp {pathToMyJar} mainClass**
in windows console it works as expected.

When I run same command in cygwin - it works too.

When I run what is intended to be run in cygwin 
**java -cp {/cygdrive/pathToMyJar} mainClass**
 - it fails, it cannot find a class.

Why I want to run it in cygwin way? Because many applications have sh scripts which calculate classpathes. If you run these scripts via cygwin it results in classpathes having that /cygdrive/ prefix. And then you start java app and it fails because java does not understand cygwin's classpath prefix.

I have read that I can force cygwin to remove that prefix: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44677/how-do-i-get-rid-of-cygwins-cygdrive-prefix-in-all-paths

OK, but a question is:

*If cygwin's default paths are not understandable for applications - how it intended to work?* What is the correct way of working with cygwin? I am pretty sure there should be some "cygwin-friendly" solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, in order for Java to understand the Cygwin paths, it would have to be compiled in a Cygwin environment.

If you’re using `sh` scripts to output paths that are intended for consumption by a Windows Java, you can use the [cygpath](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) utility to convert the paths to Windows form, e.g.,

```
$ cygpath -w ~
C:\cygwin64\home\anthony
```

---

In fact, the Cygwin documentation lists `java` as a good use case for the `cygpath` utility. From [Using Cygwin effectively with Windows](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html#using-shortcuts):

> A few programs require a Windows-style, semicolon-delimited path list, which **cygpath** can translate from a POSIX path with the -p option. For example, a Java compilation from **bash** might look like this:
>
> ```
> javac -cp "$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")" hello.java
> ```
>
> Since using quoting and subshells is somewhat awkward, it is often preferable to use **cygpath** in shell scripts.